# jQuery JSON beginner trying to create simple server request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm somewhat experienced in using JavaScript but not in dealing with jQuery and JSON.

I'm trying to create a tool that will get data from our database so that I can create new way of display our data.

If I enter the following URL into a browser, I get a response that I have identified as JSON that displays on the page:

```
**URL:** http://osuc.biosci.ohio-state.edu/hymDB/OJ_Break.getSpmInfo?cuid=OSUM%20110110&callback=test

**Response:** test({"spmInfo":{"cuid":"OSUM 110110","alt_ids":[],"loc_name":"Mad River near State Route.....
```

I've been playing around trying to build something simple that will show information from the database, but I have thus far been unsuccessful in even getting my page to display anything relevant.  Any help and advise would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="json.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="getdb.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="getinfo()">click</button>
<h6 id="objinfo"></h6>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
function getinfo(){
    $.getJSON('http://osuc.biosci.ohio-state.edu/hymDB/OJ_Break.getSpmInfo?cuid=OSUM%20110110&callback=test', function(data) {
  $('#objinfo').html(JSON.stringify(data));
});}
```

Here is a link to JSFiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/qqFJL/)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you setting a `Content-type` header of `application/json` before you print your data?

Comment: Another thing to note is that you're telling the server to call a callback function named `test`, but (at least in your JS Fiddle) you're not defining it. It's better to let jQuery handle JSON-P callbacks - for which just put `callback=?`. You may not get even this working in JS Fiddle as they may (I'm not sure) block the declaration of global vars/funcs (any JSON-P needs a global or globally-accessible function).

Comment: @WyoBuckeye - **Note:** Your Fiddle *will not* work since your function is inside `$()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an explanation of making 3rd party JSON requests that has helped me immensely.  Scroll down to the section "Retreiving JSON From Third Party Servers", which is about 2/3 down the page.  Thanks to MetalFrog for his help.

http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_JSON_%28_JavaScript_Object_Notation_%29#quickIDX9

Answer (score 1):

It's important to note that until your JSON is valid, setting the correct header will not matter. I grabbed your response from the url in your example and ran it through JSONLint to validate it.

http://jsonlint.com/

---

Here's a simple function I use to dump an array of data as a JSON response:

```
/**
 * @param $content Array of data to json_encode
 * @param bool $nocache If true, sets a no-cache header
 */
public function jsonOutput($content,$nocache = false)
{
    if( $nocache === true )
        header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    print json_encode($content);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: I'll play around with this a bit and see if that helps.  Damn, just when I think I was getting good at Javascript I get totally befuddled by something new.

Comment: @WyoBuckeye Make sure you see my edit too. Your JSON is invalid.

Comment: OK.  Thanks MetalFrog.  I think I'm just going to talk to our DB manager when I get a chance and have him help me.  It will just be a little easier that way.